# Clear Android Studio file type cache

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

This might seem weird, but for some reason Android Studio is acting up, I accidentally created a regular file called MessageC, it asked me to set the file type and I set KT. Afterwords I noticed my mistake, deleted the file and created a new KOTLIN FILE with the same name, but for some reason it seems to have stayed saved in the IDE that MessageC is regular file and not Kotlin file (as renaming it to anything else works fine). This is even after restarting the project, where can I remove this cache?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these types under **Preferences | Editor | File Types**:

- Text
- File type auto-detected by file content
- Files supported via TextMate bundles